# Removing the get values from url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
http://example.com/results.php?products=apple
```

It would be much clearer displayed as:

```
http://example.com/products/apple
```

The lines within the .htaccess file would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ results.php?products=$1 [NC]
```

These are working fine. But the problem is after this all the pages are requested to open inside

> products/

That means my **result.php** file have so many links, all the links are opened inside **product/** and shows a non-existing file in server error.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, it will tell the server that requested uri is neither a file nor a directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)/?$ results.php?products=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: I was tried your code, but still the same problem exist

Comment: **localhost/products/apple**  trying this also work, but the images including in the **results.php** are in the localhost, so thats are not displayed, after click any link, the pages are opened  in **localhost/products/** this directory, actually the files are in localhost

Comment: products is directory or just a name chosen by you?

Comment: actually **products** is a name chosen, but after that it act as a directory in URL